# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - stops at 1 insertion

Tags: c#, mysql

What I'm trying to do is that, once I insert the data, it won't insert the same user TWICE due to having multiple trials. However, I'm getting the above error. My insert statement for inserting into user is

```
bool userisExist = checkUser(personName, age, gender, handedness, comments);
                if (!userisExist)
                {
                  MySqlCommand insertUser = new MySqlCommand();
                  insertUser.Connection = c;
                  insertUser.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user (userID, name, age, gender, handedness, comments) VALUES(NULL, @personName , @age , @gender , @handedness , @comments)";


                  insertUser.Parameters.Add("@personName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = personName;
                  insertUser.Parameters.Add("@age", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = age;
                  insertUser.Parameters.Add("@gender", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gender;
                  insertUser.Parameters.Add("@handedness", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = handedness;
                  insertUser.Parameters.Add("@comments", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comments;
                  insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

                  Console.WriteLine("User Data has been inserted.");
              }
              else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("User Data already exist.");
              }
```

And my insert statement for gazeperiod is

```
insertGazePeriod.Connection = c;
              insertGazePeriod.CommandText = "INSERT INTO gazeperiod (gazeID,  duration, userID) VALUES(NULL, @duration , LAST_INSERT_ID())";


              insertGazePeriod.Parameters.Add("@duration", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = duration;

              insertGazePeriod.ExecuteNonQuery();
              Console.WriteLine("Gaze Period data has been inserted.");
                //END INSERT gazeperiod 
            }
```

And my checkUser is

```
private bool checkUser(String personName, String age, String gender, String handedness, String comments)
  {
       try
        {
            int returnValue = -1;
            MySqlCommand selectUser = new MySqlCommand();
            selectUser.Connection = c;
            selectUser.CommandText = "SELECT userID from user WHERE name= @personName AND age = @age AND gender = @gender AND handedness = @handedness AND comments = @comments";

            selectUser.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            selectUser.Parameters.Add("@personName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = personName;
            selectUser.Parameters.Add("@age", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = age;
            selectUser.Parameters.Add("@gender", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gender;
            selectUser.Parameters.Add("@handedness", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = handedness;
            selectUser.Parameters.Add("@comments", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comments;

             returnValue = (int)selectUser.ExecuteScalar();
             Console.WriteLine("returnValue-" +returnValue);
             return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("returnValue Exception-" + e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
  }
```

Right now, it's only printing the first user, and stops to print the other data as there is already a user with the current ID. I don't want multiple insertions of the same user.

Comment: where is the failure actually happening. can you limit your code to the point of failure

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your `INSERT` sql statement:

```
insertUser.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user (userID, name, age, gender, handedness, comments) VALUES(NULL, @personName , @age , @gender , @handedness , @comments)";
```

I'm pretty sure you do not want to insert `NULL` in the `userID` column. If it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, you should leave that behind.